# Cordova + Visual Studio + Android@7.0.0?

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-cordova

Has anyone been able to get the lastest android update (7.0.0) to work with visual studio?

VS says the build is successful, but when you try to deploy, the step fails because it cannot find the created output.

I *THINK* it may be a matter of updating some of the paths, but figured I'd see if anyone has already figured it out.

Given that taco.visualstudio.com hasn't seen an update since June 2017, I'm wondering if the project isn't dead :-(

```
1>------ Build started: Project: myProject, Configuration: Debug Android ------
Cordova 7.1.0
------ Platform android already exists
------ Copying native files from D:\myproject\res\native\android to D:\myproject\platforms\android
------ Done copying native files to D:\myproject\platforms\android
2>------ Deploy started: Project: myProject, Configuration: Debug Android ------
2>Could not locate the start page. You may need to build your project.
2>Deployment failed.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

EDIT: Backing down to Android@6.4.0 has resolved my immediate problem.  But it is not a long term solution.

Comment: You actually got 6.4.0 to work? I already have path issues with 6.4.0 for me 6.3.0 is the last one to work properly. I am sure it is path based, because if you look in the build folders you can see it copies the debug folder with the APK inside into VS's debug folder.

Comment: yes, seems to work for me.  I did see issues at one point, I removed all the platforms / plugins and readded them.  Now things seem ok with 6.4.0.  I did report the issue through the visual studio report problem facility.

Comment: I wonder how much that will do, I have seen people complain about that annoying nag popup about config.xml and all MS said was pretty much 'well we currently only support that version so suck it up'.

Comment: You mean the one about config.xml changing?  They're rewriting the file, so, the IDE dutifully reports the change and offers to 'help'.  That's not too bad.  I'm more worried about ongoing support for Cordova from Microsoft.

For what it's worth, this is the [link to my bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/167351/vs2017-cordova-android-breaks-with-android.html)

Its moved to a triaged state.  So, I'm hopeful.

Comment: Well yes that's what I was trying to say, they asked for cordova 7.1.0 support, and that's pretty much what MS said, so I share your concern. And yes it's good it tells you that but it is rather annoying having to change from build in to global every time you open the solution. Anyway I think it might be related to the new gradle/android studio 3 implementation that they made.

Comment: Gotcha...   given the crickets after the initial flurry... I'm going to finish my current release and start thinking about an alternative.

Comment: See, they finally decided to answer now with the typical but we support some ancient version that doesn't even work properly anymore and if you do not use that than well good luck.

Comment: yeah :-(   Disappointing, it's a nice integration, but if they don't keep it up to date, I probably won't continue to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit hacky, but here's what I got to work.

Got a clue from: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/199609/cordova-ios-640-deployment-error-due-to-change-bui.html
(although suggested path did not work for me)

I've only been looking at Android so far, so I will talk in terms of that. The cordova android platform 6.4+ puts the built apk here:

*[project]\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk*

Visual Studio seems to be looking for it here:

*[project]\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk*

I added an "after_build" hook that copies the app-debug.apk and output.json files to the folder VS is looking in. I had to manually add the folder structures (for both the location of files being copied and location of hook file). I just added the following file, and the build process picks it up automatically.

*[project]\hooks\after_build\copy_android_apk.js*

contents of copy_android_apk.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log(" -- manual step -- have to copy apk to this folder because that is where VS is looking for it...");

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var rootdir = process.argv[2];

var srcfile = path.join(rootdir, "platforms\\android\\app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\debug\\app-debug.apk");
var destfile = path.join(rootdir, "platforms\\android\\build\\outputs\\apk\\app-debug.apk");

var destdir = path.dirname(destfile);
if(fs.existsSync(srcfile) && fs.existsSync(destdir)) {
    fs.createReadStream(srcfile).pipe(
        fs.createWriteStream(destfile));
}

srcfile = path.join(rootdir, "platforms\\android\\app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\debug\\output.json");
destfile = path.join(rootdir, "platforms\\android\\build\\outputs\\apk\\output.json");

destdir = path.dirname(destfile);
if(fs.existsSync(srcfile) && fs.existsSync(destdir)) {
    fs.createReadStream(srcfile).pipe(
        fs.createWriteStream(destfile));
}
```

Comment: This is good stuff, the output path did not work for me, as coded above, it wants to use `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\platforms\android\build\outputs\app-debug.apk`

This isn't quite right, I changed the line to be:
`var destfile = path.join(process.cwd(), "bin\\Android\\Debug\\app-debug.apk");`

That seems to work nicely.

Answer (score 2):

For this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49270052/9874134, I tweaked it a bit to make it work for my case.  The "after_build" hook copies the app-debug.apk and app-release files to the folder VS is looking in.

I placed copy_android_apk.js under [project]\scripts\

[project]\scripts\copy_android_apk.js

I added an "after_build" hook element in [project]\config.xml

```
<platform name="android">
  <hook src="scripts/copy_android_apk.js" type="after_build" />
</platform>
```

contents of copy_android_apk.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

module.exports = function (context) {
    console.log(" -- manual step -- have to copy apk to this folder because that is where VS is looking for it...");

    var fs = require('fs');
    var path = require('path');
    var rootdir = process.argv[2];

    var srcfile = path.join(process.cwd(), "platforms\\android\\app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\debug\\app-debug.apk");
    var destfile = path.join(process.cwd(), "platforms\\android\\build\\outputs\\apk\\app-debug.apk");

    var destdir = path.dirname(destfile);

    //Create the output directory if it doesn't exist
    if (!fs.existsSync(destdir)) {
        mkdirSyncRecursive(destdir);
    }

    if (fs.existsSync(srcfile) && fs.existsSync(destdir)) {
        fs.createReadStream(srcfile).pipe(
            fs.createWriteStream(destfile));
    }

    srcfile = path.join(process.cwd(), "platforms\\android\\app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\release\\app-release.apk");
    destfile = path.join(process.cwd(), "platforms\\android\\build\\outputs\\apk\\app-release.apk");

    destdir = path.dirname(destfile);
    if (fs.existsSync(srcfile) && fs.existsSync(destdir)) {
        fs.createReadStream(srcfile).pipe(
            fs.createWriteStream(destfile));
    }

    /**
     * Splits whole path into segments and checks each segment for existence and recreates directory tree from the bottom.
     * If since some segment tree doesn't exist it will be created in series.
     * Existing directories will be skipped.
     * @param {String} directory
     */
    function mkdirSyncRecursive(directory) {
        var path = directory.replace(/\\$/, '').split('\\');
        for (var i = 1; i <= path.length; i++) {
            var segment = path.slice(0, i).join('/');
            !fs.existsSync(segment) ? fs.mkdirSync(segment) : null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I had to change my paths to be without the app directory and the apk name for my situation was different. var srcfile = path.join(process.cwd(), "platforms\\android\\build\\outputs\\apk\\debug\\android-debug.apk");
    var destfile = path.join(process.cwd(), "platforms\\android\\build\\outputs\\apk\\android-debug.apk");