# Visual Studio 2017 Cordova; change target folder for Android build

Tags: android, visual-studio-cordova

I have figured out how to get visual studio to compile and test with cordova 7.1.0 even though in theory it is supposed to only work with 6.3.1  But I have one more issue with Android.

Deploy is looking for the apk in platforms\android\build\outputs\apk

Build now puts the apk in platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\debug

So if I build it, then copy the apk then tell visual studio to debug, it works since it can fine the apk in platforms\android\build\outputs\apk

So every time I want to test, I have to delete the apk, built it, then copy it, then build it again to allow visual studio to deploy it.

Is there a setting in visual studio, the project, or the registry that I can use to change either the deploy folder or the build folder so they match?

Comment: Hi, Andrew - How did you configure your environment to work with Cordova 7.1.0? I'm trying to replicate the issue, but not seeing it.

Comment: I have managed to solve this problem.  I cannot remember exactly what I did to fix it.  That said, it would be really nice if VS supported newer versions of Cordova without having to override it.  Often when I load my app, VS forces it back to 6.3.1 and then I have to go to config.xml change it back to 7.1 which wastes time loading the app into VS but otherwise it seems to work pretty well.  Once in a while VS hangs during compile and I have to shut it down from task manager.

Comment: This issue is back again, not sure if a VS update caused it again.  In answer to your question, I believe the solution was to make the Windows default cordova 7.1.0 by installing that on the system.  Then it comes up as an option in the Cordova Toolset drop down as Global Cordova 7.1.0.  So I just select it there.  The problem is now worse, since copying the APK does not fix it.  I have no idea where it is looking for the file, or what name it things it needs.

Comment: i created a new blank corodova project using 6.3.1 and I get the same error.  There seems to be a bug in visual studio 2017.  It cannot deploy a debug android project to the device.  It creates the file, then cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something that appears to have worked.  I cleared the Cordova Cache, Tools/Options 
Tools for Appache Cordova
Cordova Tools

Then I restarted Visual Studio

Now it works and will publish the debug directly to the device.

Although the app launched successfully Visual Studio stopped responding, which I recall also happened once in a while after the initial update to 2017, but seemed to go away.  After restarting Visual Studio again, and Deploying the debug to Android Device, it operated properly.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the advice from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49270052/9874134 but tweaked it a bit to make it work for my case.

> The cordova android platform 6.4+ puts the built apk here:
>
> [project]\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
>
> Visual Studio seems to be looking for it here:
>
> [project]\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
>
> I added an "after_build" hook that copies the app-debug.apk and
>   output.json files to the folder VS is looking in. I had to manually
>   add the folder structures (for both the location of files being copied
>   and location of hook file). I just added the following file, and the
>   build process picks it up automatically.

The next step is a bit different to the advice.  The "after_build" hook copies the app-debug.apk and app-release files to the folder VS is looking in:

I placed copy_android_apk.js under [project]\scripts\

[project]\scripts\copy_android_apk.js

I added an "after_build" hook element in [project]\config.xml

```
<platform name="android">
  <hook src="scripts/copy_android_apk.js" type="after_build" />
</platform>
```

contents of copy_android_apk.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

module.exports = function (context) {
    console.log(" -- manual step -- have to copy apk to this folder because that is where VS is looking for it...");

    var fs = require('fs');
    var path = require('path');
    var rootdir = process.argv[2];

    var srcfile = path.join(process.cwd(), "platforms\\android\\app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\debug\\app-debug.apk");
    var destfile = path.join(process.cwd(), "platforms\\android\\build\\outputs\\apk\\app-debug.apk");

    var destdir = path.dirname(destfile);

    //Create the output directory if it doesn't exist
    if (!fs.existsSync(destdir)) {
        mkdirSyncRecursive(destdir);
    }

    if (fs.existsSync(srcfile) && fs.existsSync(destdir)) {
        fs.createReadStream(srcfile).pipe(
            fs.createWriteStream(destfile));
    }

    srcfile = path.join(process.cwd(), "platforms\\android\\app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\release\\app-release.apk");
    destfile = path.join(process.cwd(), "platforms\\android\\build\\outputs\\apk\\app-release.apk");

    destdir = path.dirname(destfile);
    if (fs.existsSync(srcfile) && fs.existsSync(destdir)) {
        fs.createReadStream(srcfile).pipe(
            fs.createWriteStream(destfile));
    }

    /**
     * Splits whole path into segments and checks each segment for existence and recreates directory tree from the bottom.
     * If since some segment tree doesn't exist it will be created in series.
     * Existing directories will be skipped.
     * @param {String} directory
     */
    function mkdirSyncRecursive(directory) {
        var path = directory.replace(/\\$/, '').split('\\');
        for (var i = 1; i <= path.length; i++) {
            var segment = path.slice(0, i).join('/');
            !fs.existsSync(segment) ? fs.mkdirSync(segment) : null;
        }
    }
}
```